# Getting NoSuchMethodError on ServerErrorException.validate in Jboss 7.1.1

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, cxf

I am developing a REST Service with POST method using JAX-RS & Apache CXF. Deployed in Jboss 7.1.1 server. When I tested, I am getting below exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;
javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException.<init>(ClientErrorException.java:88)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.findTargetMethod(JAXRSUtils.java:503)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:198)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:90)
org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:167)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
```

I used below deployment structure

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<deployment>

    <exclusions>
        <module name="javaee.api" />
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs"/>
        <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
    </exclusions>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.activation.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.annotation.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.ejb.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.el.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.enterprise.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.enterprise.deploy.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.inject.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.interceptor.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.jms.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.jws.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.mail.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.management.j2ee.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.persistence.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.resource.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.rmi.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.security.auth.message.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.security.jacc.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.servlet.jsp.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.transaction.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.validation.api" export="true" />
         // Below two are excluded to resolve duplicate classload issues
        <module name="javax.ws.rs.api" optional="true"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.crypto.dsig" optional="true"/> 


        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.xml.registry.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.xml.soap.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.xml.ws.api" export="true" />
        <!-- This one always goes last. -->
        <module name="javax.api" export="true" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

Since apache cxf servlet is dependant on javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar, So I excluded the module javax.ws.rs.api which has the same set of classes.